# Moved ASP.Net website to 64-bit machine - getting 'this page cannot be displayed'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7.5

I'm not even sure where to begin as I don't know IIS7 that well.  I moved a website (vb.net/asp.net) over from a Windows 2003 server (32-bit) to a Windows 2008 Server (64-bit).  I did this by copying the files (same as I have done to move from one server to another in the past) into the inetpub directory and then using 'create application' as well as setting up the application pool to the correct version of .NET.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- register 64-bit versions of .NET (2.0.50727, 4.0.30319) using aspnet_regiis -iru (from Framework64 directory
- create applications for the same directories as in the 2003 server
- Make sure all IIS6 compatibility stuff was installed, just in case
- Set app pool to:  enable 32-bit, .NET 2.0, tried both integrated and classic pipeline mode

When I go to the page I always get 'This page can't be displayed'.  If I change to .NET 4.0, then of course I get a 503 Server error.  I must have something set wrong, but can't for the life of me figure it out :(

Help!

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked that the App Pool the website uses is running on .Net 2.0? You might also want to try setting the Managed Pipeline to Classic.

Comment: I'll add that up top - tried both of those things :(

Comment: Follow [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS) This walks you through IIS and deployment.